# Delete Mysql entry that have foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP how could I delete an entry in table that have forgen key

table 1 : p_id
table 2 : s_id , p_id

I want to delete an entry form table 1 with will delete all entries in table 2 that have the same p_id

any Ideas ?

Comment: you should research first.. and then code.. and if you still get a problem, you should ask in stackoverflow.. its not a code writing service...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the child table (pid) is the foreign key. The use **on delete cascade** to delete the records in the child table when the parent records are deleted

Get more details here
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the parameter `ON DELETE` to `CASCADE` on your foreign key constraints configurations (sql). If you use phpMyAdmin, you can find the configurations of the constrains after selecting the table, then click on the link Relation View on your phpMyAdmin, else you need to update your relations view with a SQL query.

[image: A screenshot]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/312220Capturede769cran20160615a768024010.png))</sub>